# add active class to menu links using php

Tags: php

```
<div class="menu clearfix">
<ul>
    <li><a href="./">start</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?p=rating">rating</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?p=upload">upload</a></li>
</ul>
```

Was a while since i used php. Is there any smart way to do a foreach in php and render this menu + an "active" class to the clicked link. So if the active page is "rating", the html would render:

```
    <div class="menu clearfix">
<ul>
    <li><a href="./">start</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?p=rating" class="active">rating</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?p=upload">upload</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `$_GET` value of `p` would be `rating` (or any other link in the menu for that matter), one could do something like this:

```
<?php

        echo "<div class=\"menu clearfix\">";
        echo "<ul>";
        $links = array('rating', 'upload', 'about');
        foreach ($links as $link) {
            $active = "";
            if (!empty($_GET['p']) && $link == $_GET['p']){
                $active = 'class="active"';
            }
            echo "<li><a href=\"./?p=$link\" $active>$link</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul></div>"

?>
```

Comment: Works nice. Is there any way to modify it so that start doesnt get the get variable, but still get the active class. In other words: When you visit start.php, you dont see the `?p=start`, but the <li> for start would still get the active class

Comment: You can add a condition here and there, but I suggest you read the manual about the `$_GET` superglobal and about arrays and `foreach`. Brush the rust off, then you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to know which li is active after request.

If it is - you have to get $_GET parameter smth like $_GET['p'].

And do rendering, smth like:

```
foreach($ul as $li)
{
   if ($_GET['p'] == $li->code)
       echo 'class="active"';
}
```

For example:

```
<div class="menu clearfix">
<ul>
    <?php foreach($ul as $li): ?>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $li->url;?>" <?php echo $_GET['p']==$li->get ? class="active" : ''?>><?php echo $li->name;?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think you missed something. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in..`

Comment: It is just for example. It depends on how you create this array. Could you show your php array of li, how do you create your menu?

Comment: I dont have a php array yet, but i suppose something like `$links = array('start', 'rating', 'upload');` would do?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="sub-nav" >
<?php
    $full_name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $name_array = explode('/',$full_name);
    $count = count($name_array);
    $page_name = $name_array[$count-1];
?>
<li><a class="<?php echo ($page_name=='where-to-buy.php')?'active':'';?>" href="where-to-buy.php">WHERE TO BUY</a></li>
<li><a class="<?php echo ($page_name=='about.php')?'active':'';?>" href="about.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a class="<?php echo ($page_name=='contact.php')?'active':'';?>" href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
```

Please follow below URL to live demo...
https://webdesignerhut.com/active-class-navigation-menu/