# Add class active to the <li> tag

Tags: php, javascript

I want to add class active to the `<li>` whenever specific url is accessed?

my code look like this,

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="link1">Link1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="link2">Link2</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="link3">Link3</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="link4">Link4</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="link5">Link5</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="link6">Link6</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

if www.abc/link1 is is present in the url then only 1st li should be active and rest of them should not have any class.

Thnks in advance

Comment: you can try `cURL` I think. but you'll need to do a little digging yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add active class to menu links using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554156/add-active-class-to-menu-links-using-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you could do it with JavaScript...

```
var normalisePath = function(path) { return path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, ''); },
var path = normalisePath(window.location.pathname),
    li = document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
    i, length, a;

for (i = 0, length = li.length; i < length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

    if (normalisePath(a.pathname) == path) {
        li[i].className += ' active';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can use:

```
$("li").addClass("active");
```

You have to develop the logical part though...

**EDIT:** ...which is below:

```
$(function() {
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    var current = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
    $('a[href="' + current + '"]').addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: wow, this answer is useful. Why not just write "yes, this is possible."? btw. -1 not from me...

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a variable to the url which goes along with each page

```
www.abc/link1?link_num=1
```

Then

```
switch($_GET[link_num]){
case '1':
    $style1 = 'class=active';
    break;
case '2';
    $style2 = 'class=active';
    break;
etc...
}
```

then

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="link1?link_num=1" <?=$style1?>>Link1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="link2?link_num=1" <?=$style2?>>Link2</a>
</li>
<li>
etc
```

there's a better way i'm sure but this will do it

Comment: +1 for serverside solution which is to be preferred over clientside solution.

Answer (score 0):

check

```
var path = window.location.pathname
```

and compare it to your `li`s. Add the `active` class to the one `li`whose `a`s href is matching `path`.